# MPIRUN thread detection failed after upgrade

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have used MPI Fortran with UBUNTU for a long time. My DELL PC has 8 nodes and 16 threads.
mpirun worked with -n 16 well and gave good results. However after an upgrade (?) it stopped doing this. Now mpirun works only with n equal the number of nodes, 8. How to solve the problem and restore MPI?